# intellij + spring 'could not autowired. no bean of type found' error in latest version?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I'm using intellij ultimate version 2022.1.1(it's latest)

I just tested simple spring project generated by 'start.spring.io' default.

and make simple config code for batch testing(official guide of spring batch)

```
@Configuration
public class BatchConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
}
```

But it always told me 'could not autowired. no bean of type found' in JobBuilderFactory

and problem is, **it works well in lower version of intellij(21.3) community, ultimate version but errors in this latest version.**

and i think this is not only error. above code is just simple example and there are many errors in some parts.

some of spring codes are works well, just like `@Configuration` annotaion, but some codes doesn't works well `@Autowired`, `@EnableAutoConfiguation` and etc... of course it works well in other version.

i don't think(and i don't want to believe) this is error of intellij. there must be some other reason that i missed. but i really don't know. it's same configuration of java version and settings are fresh(del .idea folder and refresh all project settings etc...) and same gradle, path, etc...

**So what difference makes this codes wrong by intellij version? and how can i deal with? i don't want to using older version... but it's the only way?**

Comment: The community version doesn't have spring support so doesn't do any checking. The ultimate version does have spring support and does the checking hence the error. It will still work as Intellij doesn't know about the auto configuration (unless you explicitly configure the context for this).

Comment: @M.Deinum well... i missed some in content. previous version of intellij ultimate version(2021.3) works well too.

Comment: Still you need to tell the ultimate version the configuration (and enable the proper plugins). It is just intellij being drunk your app just works fine.

Comment: Could be a bug in the IDE. Please share a sample project at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA

Comment: You may try "Spring Batch" plugin

Answer (score 3):

One of the comments above by y.bedrov solved it for me, when I added the "Spring Batch" plugin in IDEA. After it installed the plugin, the error went away.

Comment: This really works! I have no idea why this problem started happening and how this plugin fixes the issue. Thankful though!